# ADOMD & Excel Integration

Tags: excel, adomd.net

All,

We have an Excel spreadsheet that uses ADOMD to query OLAP cubes and present the data in Excel. We are using version 2.8 at the moment of the ADOMD API. As far as I know there is an ADOMD.NET API for querying OLAP cubes. Can this new .NET version used from inside Excel ?

Many Thanks,
MK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADOMD.NET can only be called from .NET code which means that you can't use it inside a VBA macro. You will have to create an Excel project in Visual Studio and write your code in the .NET language of your choice. There are 3 types of Excel projects in VS2010, Excel Document, Excel Template and Excel Addin.